# How to set label ID3 tag via automated process - kid3 or mp3tag

Tags: mp3, mp4, id3, id3-tag, kid3-cli

I am using DJ software that doesn't let me filter by path/directory.

To get around that, I would like to add the directory to an id3 tag that the software recognizes.   I never use label, so that would be a good one.  However, I edit label in Serato DJ Pro and don't see it show up in kid3 or mp3tag.

I would like to set the label id3 tag, hopefully for all files under a given directory and subdirectories via command line, however if it's in a UI, that's fine too.

Does anyone know how to set the label id3 tag via kid3-cli?  Or via some other automated means?

Comment: A software not having such a basic filter sounds fishy - I'd instantly look for another. Use the `Comment` field as this exists both in ID3 for MP3 files, and as box/atom for MP4 files. In the worst case you only have space for 28 ASCII characters, so first test if your software supports reading longer comments.

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't have to be a command line tool, I recommend Mp3tag. Very easy to use, free Mp3 tagger with a GUI. Available for Windows and Mac.

You can add whatever "label" you want to the metadata in your songs. The big problem you will run into: You have to find a tag which is compatible to your Serate DJ Pro software. It is known, that this software only supports a few official id3 tags. IMHO it would be the best way to write as many tags as you can in Serato and then see in Mp3tag which one you could use for your purposes.

If you need further support, I suggest to ask in the community for Mp3tag.